# Multi display. how to fullscreen on selected/used display?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, display

Multi display. how to fullscreen on selected/used display.
I've tried `DISPLAY:=0`/`DISPLAY:=1` but that does not work on most applications...

Nvidia propetary drivers btw.

Comment: What exactly do you want to “fullscreen”? An application window?

Answer (score -2):

you need to setup Multiseats in xorg and your desktop manager.
Its not that hard, but not so easy either.

Most info is here

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg_multiseat

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: -1 Multi-seat is something entirely different than multi-monitor, even though the former can be achieved through the latter.

Comment: Well i got both working, with or without multiseats, i might or might not explain it here later, depends on how much spare time i have.